# Database/Composer Issue

Tags: mongodb, wamp, composer-php

I am not sure why I am not able to run a copy of my site on a wamp server. I am new to using mongodb and composer. What am I doing wrong? I am sorry that most of this is code but I hope you can understand what I'm saying.

cmd - mongod.exe:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Ghost>cd C:\wamp\bin\mongodb\mongodb-win32-x86_64-3.0.7\bin

C:\wamp\bin\mongodb\mongodb-win32-x86_64-3.0.7\bin>mongod.exe
2015-12-08T11:47:34.880+1000 I CONTROL  Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not
installed, will zero-out data files
2015-12-08T11:47:34.908+1000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=C:\data\db\j
ournal
2015-12-08T11:47:34.909+1000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal fil
es present, no recovery needed
2015-12-08T11:47:34.954+1000 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2015-12-08T11:47:34.956+1000 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread s
tarted
2015-12-08T11:47:35.077+1000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6
96 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=Ghost-PC
2015-12-08T11:47:35.078+1000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows Ser
ver 2003 SP2
2015-12-08T11:47:35.078+1000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.7
2015-12-08T11:47:35.078+1000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 6ce7cbe8c6b
899552dadd907604559806aa2e9bd
2015-12-08T11:47:35.078+1000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.
getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Servic
e Pack 1') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-12-08T11:47:35.080+1000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-12-08T11:47:35.083+1000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2015-12-08T11:47:35.104+1000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections
on port 27017
```

cmd - mongo.exe:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\wamp\bin\mongodb\mongodb-win32-x86_64-3.0.7\bin

C:\wamp\bin\mongodb\mongodb-win32-x86_64-3.0.7\bin>mongo.exe
2015-12-08T11:47:57.222+1000 I CONTROL  Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not
installed, will zero-out data files
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings:
2015-12-08T11:26:41.098+1000 I CONTROL  ** WARNING: --rest is specified without
--httpinterface,
2015-12-08T11:26:41.098+1000 I CONTROL  **          enabling http interface
>
```

Composer:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Ghost>cd C:\wamp\www\Project

C:\wamp\www\Project>php composer.phar install
Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommend
ed to update it by running "composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version
.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for doctrine/mongodb 1.1.6 -> satisfiable by doctrine
/mongodb[1.1.6].
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.1.6 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.6-dev -> the request
ed PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.1.6 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.6-dev -> the request
ed PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm dev-master requires doctrine/mongodb >=1.1.5,<2.0 ->
satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.1.6].
    - Installation request for doctrine/mongodb-odm dev-master -> satisfiable by
 doctrine/mongodb-odm[dev-master].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP installation is missing the PHP mongodb extension. You have to either install it completely, or just activate it in the appropriate `php.ini` file.

Run `php -i` to see where the command line PHP reads its ini file from. This info should be located at the top of this command output.